# imageType has incorrect type

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

From [this](https://api.softlayer.com/metadata/v3.1) metadata service, in data type `SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest_Block_Device_Template_Group`, it has the two below string attributes:

```
"imageType":
{
"name": "imageType",
"type": "string",
"form": "relational",
"doc": "The virtual disk image type of this template. Value will be populated on parent and child, but only supports object filtering on the parent."
},
"imageTypeKeyName":
{
"name": "imageTypeKeyName",
"type": "string",
"form": "relational",
"doc": "The virtual disk image type keyname (e.g. SYSTEM, DISK_CAPTURE, ISO, etc) of this template. Value will be populated on parent and child, but only supports object filtering on the parent."
},
```

But if we check the json data of the [rest](https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest_Block_Device_Template_Group/getPublicImages.json?objectMask=mask%5Bid%2C+name%2C+imageType%2C+accountId%5D) service, `imageType` is not a string, but a complex type:

```
"imageType":
{
"description": "a disk that may be replaced on upgrade",
"keyName": "SYSTEM",
"name": "System"
}
```

We use a `golang` client that generates go datatypes, services and methods from metadata service, this mismatch leads to unable to marshal/unmarshal the data.

Comment: {
 "imageType": {
  "name": "imageType",
  "type": "string",
  "form": "relational",
  "doc": "The virtual disk image type of this template. Value will be populated on parent and child, but only supports object filtering on the parent."
 },
 "imageTypeKeyName": {
  "name": "imageTypeKeyName",
  "type": "string",
  "form": "relational",
  "doc": "The virtual disk image type keyname (e.g. SYSTEM, DISK_CAPTURE, ISO, etc) of this template. Value will be populated on parent and child, but only supports object filtering on the parent."
 }
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There’s currently an issue reported on SoftLayer about that, although the result generated by the REST API is the correct.

Nevertheless, you could submit a ticket to SoftLayer, so that they might provide you further assistance.